# How to include a Java command in ANT to run the project

Tags: java, ant

How to include a Java command in ANT to run the project. I have searched the net and all examples creates a jar and then run it. I don'nt want to use a jar. I tried using below code, it is giving error that Java tag is not complete. My project is using TestNG so i need to give this command to run it - java -cp "/home/admin/A/":"/home/admin/A/lib/*" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

My code is as below:

```
 <target name="run" depends="jar,compile,init">
<!-- <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}-${ant.version}.jar" -->

 <java -cp "/home/admin/A/I/S/out/production/S/":"/home/admin/A/I/State/lib/*" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml >
</java>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

`<target name='run' depends="jar,compile,init">
        <java classname="org.testng.TestNG" dir="." fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="128m" >
                <classpath>
                        <pathelement location='/home/admin/A/I/S/out/production/S/' />
                        <pathelement location='/home/admin/A/I/State/lib/*' />
                </classpath>
                <arg value="testng.xml" />
        </java> 
</target>`

The second path element you can expand to individual JAR files in the lib folder or use a `path` and refer to it in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) page in the Ant Manual will help you create a correct Java tag. (Note that all content in an Ant build.xml file must be valid XML.)

However, you should probably look at use the [testng](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html) Ant task in your build file, rather than executing via Java directly.